# remove border at the bottom in toolbar and statusbar

Tags: android

I started an app from scratch in Android Studio 1,4 and the status bar and the toolbar are colored but a border appears in both. I'd like to get rid of them.

styles.xml:

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
        <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

</resources>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot?

Comment: can you show the pic also post the code of how you are placing toolbar in your xml

Comment: I was wrong they are shadows not borders

Comment: @MarianoPelizzari keep in mind that those shadows are part of the material design and only in rare cases you should remove them.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to your theme: `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>`

And this in your activity to support Android 5: `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);`